# I am trying to make a match 3 game. How can I make my script use a tween to swap pieces instead of having them teleport?

Tags: gdscript

GDScript
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhM9X.png)

I am following a YouTube tutorial of a match 3 game in GDScript.

Tweeting objects seems to be completely different. How do I adjust my script to tween the position swap of two blocks? I have been trying for a few hours and am completely stuck. Thank you.

Here's the function that controls the swapping in the game_window script

```
func swap_pieces(column, row, direction):
    var first_piece = all_pieces[column][row];
    var other_piece = all_pieces[column+direction.x][row+direction.y];
    all_pieces[column][row] = other_piece;
    all_pieces[column + direction.x][row + direction.y] = first_piece;
    first_piece.position = grid_to_pixel(column + direction.x, row + direction.y);
    other_piece.position = grid_to_pixel(column, row);




#tween animation Attempt
#var tween = get_tree().create_tween();
#tween.tween_property(first_piece, "position", other_piece, 1).from_current();
#tween.parallel().tween_property(other_piece, "position", first_piece, 1).from_current();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your all_pieces array stores references to Nodes. If this is true then I think you need to amend your tween_property lines. I've copied your line below for ease of reference:

```
tween.tween_property(first_piece, "position", other_piece, 1).from_current();
```

In this first line you have asked for the tween to move from:

first_piece -> This is fine as you've given the reference of the Node who's property you want to access.
"position" -> This is fine as you've named the property in said node
other_piece -> This is where the problem is. This value should be another position (Vector2/Vector3) but instead you are simply referencing the node.

If you replace this with the following, it should work although I can't test this right now as I don't have Godot installed on this machine.

```
tween.tween_property(first_piece, "position", other_piece.position, 1).from_current();
```

Let us know if this works or not.